# What is the width of this wrapper? "Centering a webpage"

Tags: css, html

Can you help me what CSS code does this webpage used?

http://www.meetme.com/

Specially on the pictures? I mean not all the pictures, I'm talking about the "mid div" or the content area. Well the webpage has 3 parts right?

header
body/content (mid div)
footer

here is my default image [Default Zoom](http://oi44.tinypic.com/35c4s5c.jpg)
but when I zoom it all out there are more remaining pictures. So If I make a w:1000px wrapper the webpage is centered but the remaining left and right pic wouldn't show up.

but if i make a w:100% wrapper the remaining image will show up(not sure though) but when you zoom it out it goes to the upper left corner.

Do youg et my point? :) It's too hard for me to explain I've been thinking of it about 2hours.

Maybe this would help a little. Let's just say

The header has 1000px
The body has 2000px
The footer has 1000px

So how will be the width of my wrapper(?) if 1000px well the bodyarea will overlap and the horizontal scroll will show up. and if my wrapper has 100% width. When my webpage zoom out it will go to the upper left corner also my logo will be messed up too. Also the horizontal scroll will show up too.

I want how the picture equally show up to the left and right when zoomed out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want this, but you can `margin: 0 auto;` a wrapper or container and they will center in the middle of your screen when you give them a width.

Here is a example (this will always center in the middle): http://jsfiddle.net/MWtpn/ If this is wrong, sorry.

**EDIT:**

You can see the sourcecode when you press F12 or inspect a element. The `#site_container` on http://www.meetme.com is 952px;. They are using `overflow-x: hidden;` you cannot scroll to left or right now. That gives the effect that you want I think.